# Редактирование документов Google Spreadsheets через api без использования OAuth2

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет!
Задача заключается в том, что есть некоторый скрипт, принимающий ID документа (например, в ссылке https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ahWjjkrkYrVJOMn4dyagp_hr8JECvUjj2s-dyYVzaF2/edit ID будет 1ahWjjkrkYrVJOMn4dyagp_hr8JECvUjj2s-dyYVzaF2), который открыт для редактирования по ссылке, и при запуске этого скрипта некоторые данные должны записаться в этот документ.
Сейчас это реализовано с использованием OAuth2 авторизации, которая подразумевает подтверждение доступа при первом запуске, создание файла с данными авторизации и работу с ними в дальнейшем, пока не придёт запрос с другим ID документа. В таком случае будет запрошено новое подтверждение и файл будет перезаписан.
Авторизация реализуется таким кодом, взятым из доки:

```
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    $credentialsPath = $this->expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }

    return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path)
{
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
    }

    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}
```

Вопрос: есть ли способ редактировать открытые для редактирования по ссылке документы только по api key, без подтверждения?
P.S. гуглил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод getClient получился на порядок проще:

```
define('CREDENTIALS_FILE', 'project-name-dafd89e206c0.json');

function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setAuthConfig(CREDENTIALS_FILE);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);

    return $client;
}
```

Файл project-name-dafd89e206c0.json получаем [здесь](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=project-name), создаём учётные данные (ключ сервисного аккаунта), включаем api для spreadsheets [здесь](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=project-name) и, собственно, всё. Может, кому-нибудь пригодится.